# Increment a particular column in a unique manner in MongoDB

Tags: python, reactjs, mongodb, flask

I'm currently working on an application which uses ReactJS, Python Flask and MongoDB. I loaded the data into MongoDB from a Kaggle dataset. The database now contains over 50000 records.
Every document contains a key called id which is unique across the documents.
Here is how a sample document looks like:
[image]

Now, I want to perform an insertion from the React frontend and insert values into the database but while inserting, I don't want to the user to enter the id key but want to anyway load the id in the database in such a manner that it should maintain the uniqueness across the documents. I know there's _id which MongoDB automatically gives us for uniqueness, I want to keep that but I also want to keep the id key unique in all the documents. Does anyone know how to do that? So far, I'm able to insert documents in Mongo from the frontend but still figuring how to add the unique id.

Here is the backend Flask code:

```
@app.route('/insert', methods=["POST"])
@cross_origin()
def insert():
    try:
        newRow = request.get_json()
        newRow['posting_date'] = datetime.datetime.now()
        print('received: ', newRow)
        dbResponse = db.vehicles.insert_one(newRow)
        return flask.jsonify(message="Success")

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

As you can see, I'm getting all the information from the frontend (which doesn't include id by the way) and storing it in the newRow variable. After that, I'm adding the **posting_date** key which will contain the present time inside that variable. I'm then inserting the JSON into the vehicles collection. Now, as I had mentioned, like how I added **posting_date**, I also want to add **id** but it should not already be present in the previous collections.

Please help me on this.

Comment: hi, perhaps use a uuid if global uniqueness is needed https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb

Comment: They have given an example of uniqueIdentifierCounter where they are increment the counter but that's a separate collection, isn't it? How can I link that value with my id? Is it possible for you to help me with the code

Comment: Also, please can you upvote my question? I've got a warning from StackOverflow that if my question gets downvoted, I won't be able post further questions and my account will be blocked!